# How to pass a stack to a function when the function modifies the stack?

Tags: c++, stl

Here are the constraints :

1. Only  STL must be used for stack creation (do not use struct to create stack)
2. Sort the stack without using any loops

I have figured out the solution with constraint 2. But when I create a stack using STL to satisfy constraint 1, the stack is not getting sorted and the output is just same as the input.

Expected Output : 5 4 3 2 1
My Output       : 1 2 4 3 5

Below is the code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;

void SortedInsert(stack<int> S,int x)
{
    if(S.empty() || x > S.top())
        S.push(x);
    else
    {
        int temp = S.top();
        S.pop();
        SortedInsert(S,x);
        S.push(temp);
    }

}


void StackSort(stack<int> S)
{
    if(!S.empty())
    {   
        int x = S.top();
        S.pop();        
        StackSort(S);
        SortedInsert(S,x);
    }
}

void main()
{
    int arr[5] = {1,2,4,3,5};

    stack<int> S;

    for(int i=4 ; i>=0 ; i--)
        S.push(arr[i]);

    StackSort(S);

    while(!S.empty())
    {
        cout<<S.top()<<" ";
        S.pop();
    }

    cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the stack by reference or as a pointer.

Example for "by reference":

```
void StackSort(stack<int> &S)
{
    if(!S.empty())
    {   
        int x = S.top();
        S.pop();        
        StackSort(S);
        SortedInsert(S,x);
    }
}
```

Call it like this: `StackSort(S);`

Example for "by pointer":

```
void StackSort(stack<int> *S)
{
    if(!S->empty())
    {   
        int x = S->top();
        S->pop();        
        StackSort(S);
        SortedInsert(S,x);
    }
}
```

Call it like this: `StackSort(&S);`

**You need to change `SortedInsert` accordingly.**

Answer (score 2):

Pass the stacks by reference or by pointer. You are currently only modifying local copies.

```
void StackSort(stack<int> &S)
```

or

```
void StackSort(stack<int> *S)
```